# Laravel login redirects back to login page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I'm a beginner to Laravel 5.5.* and I'm trying to create a login page.
 
whenever i click the login button i'm redirected back to the login form.

Here are my steps:

1. `php artisan make:auth`
2. `php artisan make:migration table_name_here`
3. I modified the migration
4. `php artisan migrate`

## Here is my LoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

}
```

## Here is my User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'department', 'phone', 'status', 'roleId',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

## My web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

## My table columns

*staffId,
roleId,
firstname,
lastname,
username,
email,
department,
phone,
status,
remember_token,
created_at,
updated_at,
password,*

Comment: That `public function showLoginForm()` is not part of the default `LoginController`

Comment: just removed `public function showLoginForm()`from the `LoginController`, it didn't work

Comment: What are you trying to log in with; username and password / email and password?

Comment: I'm using email.

Comment: I'm using email.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Yeah, It was a problem with the middleware

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue having `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true` set while migrating from an old to a new production server to a new one. HTTPS was not set up set.

By removing `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true`, logging in started working again.

Of course, set up HTTPS and add the env var back before actually migrating servers for real.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart apache server and again  run php artisan serve command may this will help you to short out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that the login redirected to the login page without any errors.

For me I didn't had any name tag in my input field of my form e.g.
So it didn't know what data to send the in the request

```
<input type="email">
<input type="password">
```

Should be

```
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="password" name="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am able to solve this problem, when I set the SESSION_DOMAIN 'NULL' in session.php in local development environment.